# Dismiss diary appointment alert

Tags: calendar, diary

I have set Emacs to [alert](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Appointments.html) me via a `window` 30 minutes before an appointment. This is working as expected. However, every three minutes thereafter, Emacs continues to alert me to the same appointment. How do I dismiss/acknowledge the reminder and prevent it from triggering repeatedly?

Comment: Only a workaround, but what about prolonging the time between reminders?  E.g.: (setq appt-display-interval 10)

Comment: Are you saying that for *any* appointment in your diary, you want *exactly one* notification, 30 minutes beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

`M-x appt-delete` is a possibility to delete entries from the appointment list.

See also (info "(emacs) Appointments").